# Pgpool tries to write to slave machine

Tags: replication, pgpool

It occured only once - pgpool (newest version) allowed application to write to a slave machine. The only error message I have is like that: "cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction", nothing more in postgres logs or anywhere. Anyone had a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

This once happened to me when **SELECT ...** statement contains a function that changes data. Using **[black_function_list](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#BLACK_FUNCTION_LIST)** fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In replication mode (replication_mode = on),the SELECT is load balanced and only one of the PostgreSQL servers receives the command. Solution would be:

1) Add "/*REPLICATION*/" comment in front of the SELECT.

2) Add func1 to the black_function_list.

The seconed chance is if master is down the slave will act as master , since slave is set as read only, it will show error